# Dispose a user control in Closing or Closed event?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a user control with bitmaps that should be disposed when the form closes. Is it better to do this in the form's Closing event, Closed event, or somewhere else?

Part 2: 
Inside a user control, when its form closes, should a bitmap be disposed in the Disposed event or somewhere else?

Comment: The `Closing` event. The `Closed` event will be too late.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the form has no business messing with private members of the user control.  The universal .NET rule applies here as well, a class needs to dispose its members in its own Dispose() method.  It will run automatically when the form closes, no assistance is needed.

There's a quirk however, the project item template for UserControl is awkward.  It puts the Dispose() method inside the control's Designer.cs file.  Best thing to do is to cut+paste this method into the control's main source file.  After you edited the method, it ought to resemble this:

```
    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        someBitmap.Dispose();             // <== added
        someOtherBitmap.Dispose();
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Some programmers *really* dislike tinkering with the Designer.cs file, do note that there's nothing to worry about since the code is outside the #region marked `Component Designer generated code`.  The alternative is to use the Disposed event:

```
    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Disposed += UserControl1_Disposed;
    }

    void UserControl1_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        someBitmap.Dispose();
        someOtherBitmap.Dispose();
    }
```